# Frame vs. center contradiction

Tags: ios, frame, center

How is this possible? Shouldn't the following be true?

```
v.center == CGPointMake(v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.x/2), v.frame.origin.y + v.frame.size.y)/2)
```

And if so, then how do you explain this result I'm getting? Here is the code:

```
                 NSLog(@"sv    center: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(sv.center));
                 NSLog(@"piece center: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(piece.center));
                 NSLog(@"sv     frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(sv.frame));
                 NSLog(@"piece  frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(piece.frame));
```

There is no code between the NSLog statements that I omitted. I note that when I break right after this, po sv.superview and po piece.superview both return the same object. Anyway, the result of these statements is:

```
... sv    center: {228.934, 120.684}
... piece center: {124.28, 51.1536}
... sv     frame: {{2.52823, -9.70338}, {122.04, 122.04}}
... piece  frame: {{63.2595, -9.86644}, {122.04, 122.04}}
```

Doing the math, by the frames listed, I would expect the centers to be `{62.284115, 56.16831}` and `{92.64975, 56.08678}`, respectively. If I can't derive the center from the frame as just described, what else could I be missing?

Here is the result from po sv.superview:

`3 = 0x1f8d0290 <Palette: 0x1f8d0290; frame = (2.017e-05 1.64772e-06; 1024 748); transform = [2.39836, 0, 0, 2.39836, 0, 0]; tag = 42; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f8b9b60>>`

Here is the result from po piece.superview:

`$2 = 0x1f8d0290 <Palette: 0x1f8d0290; frame = (2.017e-05 1.64772e-06; 1024 748); transform = [2.39836, 0, 0, 2.39836, 0, 0]; tag = 42; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f8b9b60>>`

Both piece and sv are of the same class, which is a subclass of UIImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem probably is that your `transform` property is not the identity transform. In this case, the `frame` property is simply not defined, see the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):
"Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored."

Comment: Interesting. I've never noticed that warning before. That's true. the transform is not the identity. The superview is scaled. But I thought there was always a frame. The same code has worked properly on other views similarly scaled, so I couldn't figure out what was different here. With this in mind, I'll have to carefully review my entire app. The whole app involves translating and scaling views.

Comment: I'll run some tests and mark this as the answer if testing confirms it (I have no reason at this point to doubt it).

Comment: Oops! I should have caught this when I first replied to your post. The transform of sv and piece are the identity. It is the transform of their superview that is not the identity. So my dilemma is still there.

Comment: I take it back. I did have a transform that I was using to compensate for the transform (scaling) of the superview. It was just a translation transform. After changing that code from applying a translation transform to resetting centers, the code works as expected.